# Homogeneous prime ideals over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, finite-fields, projective-space, projective-varieties

is there a nice description for the *homogeneous prime ideals* in the ring $\mathbb{F}_q[x,y,z]$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is any given finite field ?

Thanks !